# How to change the used html file in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to change the html file used in the Electron app. I tried several suggestions here on StackOverFlow, but I am unable to achieve anything. My code is as follows:

main.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="renderer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>One</h1>
        <button id="change">Change</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

new.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Two</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {  // Create the browser window.  
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({    width: 800,    height: 600 })
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {  
    createWindow()
    app.on('activate', function () {     
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()  
    })
})
```

renderer.js:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
const path = require('path')

const newWindowBtn = document.getElementById('change')

newWindowBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 400, height: 320 })

  win.on('close', () => { win = null })
  win.loadFile("new.html");
})
```

I am trying to change the html file to new.html once one clicks on the button in the index.html.

Comment: You ceate a BrowserWindow in the renderer process and it shouldn't be. Your BrowserWindow already exists (you have created it in your main.js). So keep a reference of it in your main.js and from your Button click handler send an IpcRenderer message to the main which will be listening with a handler on this message. Eventually in this handler load your already existing BrowserWindow with the new html file.

Comment: Just use a basic link: `<a href="new.html">Change</a>`

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `location.href='new.html'` in this function to change page in one window.